# Detecting a website language (for crawling)

Tags: php, html, encoding, internationalization, multilingual

I am working on a crawler and I cannot seem to properly detect the website's text language.

Most of the time I just need to detect if the text on the website is Russian, Chinese or Japanese.

Are there any known solutions for this? The percent of website that specify language in html tags is very low.

Comment: Those are very distinct languages. Naive solution would be to look for language specific characters I guess

Comment: that was what I tried, but I failed at getting the website text properly because encoding of each website is unknown.

Comment: http://detectlanguage.com/

Comment: @user3806621 if I would use an external service for each "simple" problem like this, then my site would become a mess.

Comment: Not answering the question, wikipedia [has a nice chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Language_recognition_chart) concerning language recognition based on the characters / words used. Just for your information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you are doing this in, but if it was me, I would do this first:

Determine the character set/encoding. This will already tell you what language the website is in:

- If it is EUCJP or SJIS: Japanese
- If it is Big5 or GB: Chinese
- If it is KOI8-R: Russian

You could add more charsets to test against.

However, if it is UTF/Unicode, do the following:

- Have three counters of Unicode character groups:

  - Cyrillic 0x0400 - 0x052f
  - CJK for Chinese/Japanese 0x4e00 - 0x9fff
  - Kana for Japanese 0x3040 - 0x30ff
- Fetch the pages
- Use some XML parser to get the content from `div`s, `p`s, `td`s, etc. Common content tags.
- For every character, determine which group it belongs to and increase its counter

Now you have 3 counters. If the first counter is high, chances are it is Russian. If the second counter is high, with quite a lot of the 3rd counter, it is Japanese. If the second counter is high, with none of the 3rd counter, it is Chinese (or maybe Korean, but there is an Hangul bucket you could add for this).

Check [this page](http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/) to add blocks to your algorithm as you like.